# EXCEL 2010 Run-time error '50290' Method "_Evaluate' of object'_Worksheet' failed

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

Then i double click on cell with data validation and then try to select from dropdown I get error Runtime error Run-time error '50290'. Method "_Evaluate' of object'_Worksheet' failed

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Select Case Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Case Is < 5
        LastRow = 5: CountRow = 0: R = 1
    Case Is > 5
        LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row: CountRow = LastRow - 4: R = 0
    Case 5
        LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row: CountRow = LastRow - 4: R = 1
End Select
End Sub
```

on

```
Select Case Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
case 1
      msgbox "hello"
end select
```

Runtime error Run-time error '50290'. Application-defined or object-defined error.

on

```
Select Case Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Range("A1"), SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
```

Why this happens?

Comment: Which version of Excel? I can't replicate the problem in 2013 with either `Range("A1")` or `[A1]`

Comment: OK, I can replicate in 2010. It's nothing to do with the After parameter specifically as it occurs even if you leave that out. The only solution I can see is not to double-click before clicking the dropdown, or add an error handler so that the first call simply exits - see revised answer.

Comment: isn't `After:=Range("A1")` equal to "A0", with `SearchDirection := xlPrevious` ?  wich doesn't exist... (or maybe i'm still not wake up enough)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
After:=Range("A1")
```

rather than:

```
After:=[A1]
```

Edit: neither of these fixes it in 2010. However a simple error handler seems to resolve the first change event issue (the double-click then selecting the DV dropdown actually fires two change events:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    On Error GoTo err_handle
    Select Case Cells.Find(What:="*", after:=[A1] SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        Case Is < 5
            lastrow = 5: CountRow = 0: R = 1
        Case Is > 5
            lastrow = Cells.Find(What:="*", after:=[a1], SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row: CountRow = lastrow - 4: R = 0
        Case 5
            lastrow = Cells.Find(What:="*", after:=[a1], SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row: CountRow = lastrow - 4: R = 1
    End Select
err_handle:
End Sub
```

Comment: The fact that the error mentioned Evaluate (and [] is, more or less, a call to Evaluate) made me think it was worth changing to an explicit Range call.

Comment: Error still appears if not switch off Break on all errors

Comment: Correct. There is nothing you can do about that in code. Your only option is to not double-click the cell first (I don't know why you would).

Comment: Depends on your point of view, I suppose. I would say yes, given that the behaviour has been changed in 2013.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into error 50290 in a spreadsheet using WinHTTP in async mode to check links/download data. According to [this www.pcreview.co.uk thread](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/error-50290-error-writing-to-worksheet-while-using-an-activex-control.957374/), this error comes up when a script tries to write to a workbook when Excel is not ready. You can test the ready state of the Excel application with `Application.Ready`.

Using this code before writing to the workbook worked in my script:

```
Do While Not Application.Ready
  DoEvents
Loop
```